# removeChild after setimeout - works sporadically?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, removechild

good evening.

I have a loader which overlays the site, fades out via a css transition (opacity), which lasts 1000ms when the body class is changed to "loaded", and then once the transition is finished, I remove it from the DOM.

i am using the following script which works just fine in everything bar osx snow leopard/google chrome v28, and even then only for a few folks - i have the exact same set up, as does my client and pretty much everyone i can get to test - and it works fine.

BUT I've had 2 or 3 bug reports where the loader is not being removed from the DOM, so it still overlays the rest of the content and makes the elements under it un-clickable. one kind user even sent me a video which confirms that the loader element is still in the DOM.

the script is as per below; i am wondering whether there could be an issue with either how i've removed the element, or with the setTimeout function syntax itself.

any help as to why this could possibly be failing would be appreciated, particularly considering I am unable to replicate this! I have added comments in the script to explain how i expect it to work (and how for the most part it does).

```
var 
loaded = false,
_body = document.body,
loader = document.getElementById("loader"),
kill_loader = function() {
    if ( loader ) {
        loader.parentNode.removeChild(loader);
    }
},
cl = function() {
    // set loaded to true, add class to body that fades the loader, then remove the loader
    loaded = true;
    _body.className = _body.className + " loaded";
    // the above works as intended
    setTimeout(kill_loader,1000);
    // this last bit does not seem to work in rare instances as detailed. 
    // the timeout is so that the loader fully fades before being removed. 
};

window.onload = function() {
    if ( !loaded ) {
    // if loaded variable is false (i.e. cl() has not run), call the function to complete loading
        cl();
    }
};


setTimeout(function () {
    // if page still not loaded after 5 seconds, force the load
    if( !loaded ) {
        cl();
    }
},5000);
```

thank you in advance people for any help you can give.

Comment: If you can't replicate it, could you ask your users to report any console errors? Are your variables global?

Comment: ...this isn't directly relevant, but as a matter of form, I'd move your `if ( !loaded ) {` to the `cl()` function so that you're not having to repeat it. Then you can do `window.onload = cl` and `setTimeout(cl, 5000)`

Comment: Is this code in a ready function? I'm wondering if the problem is maybe that "loader" is null when you call that function because in some weird case the html wasn't rendered yet. Where is this script on the page? Is it after the html?

Comment: Then it could simply be that he's running some code that is conflicting with yours, or that is crashing and halting the rest of the script if he happened to combine the files. Also possible that he has an element with the same `"loader"` ID. Ultimately, if the user is causing a conflict, there's little you can do. It's his issue. You may want to choose a more obscure ID in place of `"loader"` though.

Comment: Did your users report browser versions?

Comment: ok thanks for your comments Crazy Train. Unfortunately I can't seem to reach the folks that highlighted the bug initially :( I will tidy up that cl function as you mentioned, cheers.

Comment: If the user didn't provide a working demonstration of the bug, then the bug never happened. Videos don't cut it! :-)

Comment: @matty-d the js is right at the bottom of the page, and not wrapped in any other function.

Comment: @sabof chrome v28 on OSX 10.6.8 (which i have, but can't replicate!)

Comment: @crazy train 3 users (albeit out of thousands!) have reported this, so i don't believe it can be unique to that one setup.

Comment: Wrap your code in an immediately invoked function so that you're not creating a bunch of global variables. Only expose the variables that are needed by your users, if any. It could be as simple as your users creating a global with the same name.

Comment: @crazy train so `(function(){ // blah }()); ` wrapping everything you mean?

Comment: @organdonor47: Correct. It'll at least scope your variables so that they don't conflict with globals. And as a safety measure, put a `;` before the first `(` as well so that if your code is combined with some other code, and the other code doesn't terminate its final statement, the `()` won't be interpreted as a function call operation on the previous expression.

Comment: ok thanks so much @crazy train, will give this a whirl and just keep my fingers crossed - everything still works as expected so at least i've not broken anything, and hopefully this will scoop up those stray few folk. 

by the nature of the problem I can't say that this is a fix yet, but will check back as soon as I hear anything, and add your solution as the answer (is that the correct way to do things round here?)

Answer (score 0):

ok the solution was unrelated to my script per se, but due to a chrome plugin installed (measureIt.js) that was killing my script. brilliant.

I have managed to replicate the problem (which was not limited to OSX or chrome version incidentally) with the plugin installed and added a simple `try catch` statement for the removing of the loader.

thank you to Crazy Train for helping me tidy the syntax up - it made isolating the problem a little easier.